# Filtered date range function

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function to produce an inclusive range of `Day` such that Saturdays are excluded.

```
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Data.Time.Calendar.WeekDate

let sel3 (_, _, x) = x
let dateRange d1 d2 = takeWhile (<= d2) [ d | d <- map (flip addDays d1) [1..], (sel3 . toWeekDate) d /= 6]
```

I believe the code is correct as written, but I'd like to know if there's anything non-idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing compiled Haskell (`import ...`) with GHCi commands (top-level `let`s).

Top-level definitions should all be given type signatures, e.g.,

```
sel3 :: (a, b, c) -> c
```

Try to break down your functions into semantically interesting (and therefore nameable) chunks. For instance, `(sel3 . toWeekDate) d /= 6` is a proposition on `Day`s to ensure it isn't Saturday. So say that.

```
-- Usage: isSaturday (fromWeekDate 2016 06 22) == False
--        isSaturday (fromWeekDate 2016 06 25) == True
isSaturday :: Day -> Bool
isSaturday d = weekday d == 6
  where
    weekday :: Day -> Int
    weekday = sel3 . toWeekDate
```

Take advantage of available instances! [`Day`s are instances of `Enum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.6.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Calendar.html#t:Day), so you can enumerate them directly without that messy `map` and `takeWhile` you've got going on.

```
rangeWithoutSaturdays :: Day -> Day -> [Day]
rangeWithoutSaturdays start end = filter (not . isSaturday) [start .. end]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Would it be more appropriate to make `isSaturday` a `where` clause, since it's unlikely to be useful generally?

Comment: Maybe! A few things to keep in mind though—1) Deep nesting (`where`s within `where`s) starts to get pretty ugly and can make it difficult to follow flow in a function. 2) Testing. 3) Module export lists. 4) Documentation. I try to keep the number of tricky or non-obvious things in a function to one, like the magic number `6` meaning Saturday. Too many clever or non-obvious things in one place makes for difficult reading, and vertical space is cheap.